# Getting error in parsing an XML file using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, jdom

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootElement>
   <Achild>
      .....
   </Achild>
</RootElement>
```

How can I check if the document contains `Achild` element or not? I tried

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
// Use the factory to create a builder
try {
    final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    final Document doc = builder.parse(configFile);
    final Node parentNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
    final Element childElement = (Element) parentNode.getFirstChild();
    if(childElement.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(...
```

but it gives me an error (`childElement` is null).

Comment: *What* is `null`, childElement itself, it's node name or something else?

Comment: Do you mean a tag called "AChild" or do you mean a child node in general?

Comment: I mean a child node with name "Achild"

Comment: is giving something like [#text....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're getting `#text` node (that between `<RootElement>` and `<Achild>`) as first child (that's pretty common mistake), for example:

```
final Node parentNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
Node childElement = parentNode.getFirstChild();
System.out.println(childElement.getNodeName());
```

Returns:

```
#text
```

Use instead:

```
final Node parentNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList childElements = parentNode.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < childElements.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Node childElement = childElements.item(i);
    if (childElement instanceof Element)
        System.out.println(childElement.getNodeName());
}
```

Wanted result:

```
Achild
```

**EDIT:**

There is second way using [`DocumentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace%28boolean%29) method:

```
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
```

However this works only in validating mode, so you need to provide DTD in your XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE RootElement [
    <!ELEMENT RootElement (Achild)+>
    <!ELEMENT Achild (#PCDATA)>
]>
<RootElement>
   <Achild>some text</Achild>
</RootElement>
```

and set `factory.setValidating(true)`. Full example:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document doc = builder.parse("input.xml");

final Node rootNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
final Element childElement = (Element) rootNode.getFirstChild();

System.out.println(childElement.getNodeName());
```

Wanted result with original code:

```
Achild
```

Comment: @Saurabh: You're welcome. Note that JDOM API (http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/) is a different thing from standard Java DOM API (this included in JDK).

Comment: I have a question like on doing parentNode.getChildNodes(); will get me sub childnodes of ACHild also or just childs of RootElement.Because I don't want subchilds of Achild and if he is iterating over that then it will cost me performance wise....:)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like .getFirstChild() is returning you a text node containing the white space between "" and "", in which case you would need to advance to the next sibling node to get to where you expect.